# Why can minimizing $\|w\|$ be solved by minimizing $\frac{\|w\|^2}{2}$?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, optimization

I was watching the MIT open course on machine learning. In the session on SVM, the professor derived that the margin is $\frac{1}{\|w\|}$. However, the professor then said for the convenience of mathematics, to maximize $\frac{1}{\|w\|}$, which implies to minimize $\|w\|$, is minimizing $\frac{\|w\|^2}{2}$.

What is the rationale behind this substitution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice that $\frac{1}{x}$ is a decreasing function over the positive domain and $\frac{x^2}{2}$ is an increasing function over the non-negative domain.

If $g$ is a decreasing function (a function where as the input increases, the output decreases). Maximizing $f_1(x)$ is equivalent to minimizing  $g(f_1(x))$. Here $f_1(w)=\frac{1}{\|w\|}$, and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, hence $g(f_1(w))=\|w\|$.

If $h$ is an increasing function (a function where if the input increases, the output increases, similarly, if the input decreases, the output decreases). Minimizing $f_2(x)$ is equivalent to minimizing $h(f_2(x))$. Here $f_2(w)=\|w\|$ and $h(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}$, hence $h(f_2(w))=\frac{\|w\|^2}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you Siong! But we're forcing $||w||$, a linear function, to change to $\frac{||w||^2}{2}$ the convex function. It makes me feel uncomfortable.

Comment: Perhaps working with some example might help, let $w$ be one dimension, such that $3 \le w \le 5$, you can check that both $|w|$ and $|w|^2$ share the same maximum and minimum point. thanks to the monotonicity. maximizing $|w|^3$ gives you the same result too since it is increasing over the domain  $3 \le w \le 5$.